# Static fragment prevents me from accessing my data object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a new Tabbed Activity from Android Studio. This gives me an activity and a fragment. I want the tabs to go through a list that is in some MyData db object instanciated in the onCreate method (so far so good).

I put in the tabs layout fragment_tabbed.xml a button and a viewtext that I would like to change accordingly to the elements of y list when browsing. The button is supposed to do some action such as db.delete(id).

My problem is that I don't know how to attach this action to the button and update it as the tab on display changes. I tried in the onCreateView but it complains that "Tabbed.this.db cannot be referenced from a static context". I tried to just remove the "static" but I the editor complains that "fragment inner class should be static".

I got the trick of using an argument bundle to pass my text data (which is not really convenient by the way, can't I get my data from my db object?), but not how to deal with the button's action as I want to act on my db object. How can I get around this? I tried to update the whole button's action but I suppose I could just update some argument containing just the id that I could update with the same trick as the text, and have it passed as some argument by a more general onClick action, but I lack experience and could use some hints.

The following code is mostly what was generated by Android Studio, with my attemp to add listener on the button.

```
public class Tabbed extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private MyData db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        db = new MyData();

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            Button buttonDelete = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_del);
            buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View view) {
                    Tabbed.this.db.delete(
                            getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your inner fragment is declared as `public static class`, instances of this class do not hold a reference to the outer class. As such, you can't get a reference to the fragment's activity by writing `Tabbed.this`.

However, you can get a reference to the activity in a different way. Because your app is simple, you *know* that all `PlaceholderFragment` instances will be running inside of `Tabbed` activity instances. So you can just write this:

```
@Override
public void onClick (View view) {
    Tabbed tabbed = (Tabbed) view.getContext();
    tabbed.db.delete(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The tabs correspond to a list in db. When I delete one of those (using what you suggested), it doesn't seem to affect the tabs I can browse. I got an error suggesting I add a notifyDataChange so I did add `tabbed.mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
after the delete action in the onClick. I tried to add a boolean value to my list elements so that I can set it on/off and display it in the tab, it seems to be working, but as I pass a few tabs and come back it is back to the default value. I tried to display the size of tabbed.db.list, I got a null pointer error.